# Write back to Oracle from PowerApps

Tags: sql, oracle, powerapps

I am trying write back to Oracle table from PowerApps. But I'm getting the following error:

> "The Data source is read-only, so the function Patch can't write to it"

I have access to this Oracle table and table data is also visible in my PowerApp but I cannot insert in DB from my PowerApp.

Primary key is perfectly fine, defined well with all constraints. I can insert by using SQL query in the same table but when I do same with PowerApps I get error.

Here is my Patch function.

```
Patch('[PLAN].[V_PLAN_L_TYP]',Defaults('[PLAN].[V_PLAN_L_TYP]') , {TYP_ID: TYP_ID_TextInput.Text, TYP_DESC: TYP_DESC_TextInput.Text,
KANAL_AKT: KANAL_AKT_TextInput.Text } );
```

Is it possible to write back to Oracle table or not?

Comment: error says your connection with Oracle is read only, can you simply try creating a record (not patch) rather crate a record and see if you can do so? may be it can help narrow down the issue

Comment: What did you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

This naming convention `V_PLAN_L_TYP` sounds to me like a view but not a table. Please verify it.

This is why that matters - Currently [Oracle connector documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/oracle/) says:

> Support Oracle view as read-only table

Comment: Yes it is view. I'm new bie and my colleague told me I can only insert in DB with view, I cannot insert directly in table. I tried to insert directly in PLAN_L_TYP but then I get error which says " Function Patch has some invalid arguments ".

Comment: @FarheenShafqat edit the question, add the new PATCH & error details pls

Comment: Patch is same I tried with Table name PLAN_L_TYP but it's not working. I have trial version Can it be the reason? I made simple canvas App. It that ok? or should i make model driven app?

Comment: @FarheenShafqat Model driven cannot connect to Oracle, Canvas is the way to go. Trial should not be the problem. The problem may be with schema name for ex. TYP_ID may not be right table column name, could be view column alias..

Comment: Ok then maybe the  cause is View. Powerapps doesn't support Oracle views maybe that's why I'm gtting error. But the problem is I don't have access to tables, I can only see views. Gateway is made for Production and in Production I can only see views. What you will recommend? What are the possibilities now?

Comment: @FarheenShafqat you don’t have a choice, either read-only with view, or ask Prod table write access.. if this answer helped you, accept/upvote it..

Comment: @FarheenShafqat Or some custom API approach is also possible..

Comment: Can you please elaborate bit more about custon API ?? Any link will be very helpful.

Comment: @FarheenShafqat read [this](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/register-and-use-custom-apis-in-powerapps/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/register-custom-api)